# Reload table data when select menu item is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jhipster

I have this table with select menu:

```
export interface IActivePairsProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ url: string }> {}

export const ActivePairs = (props: IActivePairsProps) => {
  const [paginationState, setPaginationState] = useState(
    overridePaginationStateWithQueryParams(getSortState(props.location, ITEMS_PER_PAGE, 'id'), props.location.search)
  );

  const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = useState('');

  const getAllEntities = () => {
    props.getEntities(paginationState.activePage - 1, paginationState.itemsPerPage, `${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}`);
    props.getExchangesList();
  };

  const sortEntities = () => {
    getAllEntities();
    const endURL = `?page=${paginationState.activePage}&sort=${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}&exchangeId=${exchangeId}`;
    if (props.location.search !== endURL) {
      props.history.push(`${props.location.pathname}${endURL}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sortEntities();
  }, [paginationState.activePage, paginationState.order, paginationState.sort]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    const page = params.get('page');
    const sort = params.get('sort');
    if (page && sort) {
      const sortSplit = sort.split(',');
      setPaginationState({
        ...paginationState,
        activePage: +page,
        sort: sortSplit[0],
        order: sortSplit[1],
      });
    }
    const exchangeId = params.get('exchangeId');
  }, [props.location.search]);

  const sort = p => () => {
    setPaginationState({
      ...paginationState,
      order: paginationState.order === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc',
      sort: p,
    });
  };

  const handlePagination = currentPage =>
    setPaginationState({
      ...paginationState,
      activePage: currentPage,
    });

  const handleSyncList = () => {
    sortEntities();
  };

  const { activePairsList, exchangesList, match, loading, totalItems } = props;

  return (
    <div>          
      <div className="table-responsive">
        {activePairsList && activePairsList.length > 0 ? (
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                .....
                    <select onChange={e => setExchangeId(e.target.value)}>
                      {exchangesList
                        ? exchangesList.map(otherEntity => (
                            <option value={otherEntity.exchangeId} key={otherEntity.exchangeId}>
                              {otherEntity.exchangeLongName} - {otherEntity.exchangeId}
                            </option>
                          ))
                        : null}
                    </select>
                  .........
          </Table>
        ) : (
          !loading && <div className="alert alert-warning">No Active Pairs found</div>
        )}
      </div>
      {props.totalItems ? (
        <div className={activePairsList && activePairsList.length > 0 ? '' : 'd-none'}>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <JhiItemCount page={paginationState.activePage} total={totalItems} itemsPerPage={paginationState.itemsPerPage} />
          </Row>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <JhiPagination
              activePage={paginationState.activePage}
              onSelect={handlePagination}
              maxButtons={5}
              itemsPerPage={paginationState.itemsPerPage}
              totalItems={props.totalItems}
            />
          </Row>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ activePairs, exchangesList }: IRootState) => ({
  activePairsList: activePairs.entities,
  exchangesList: exchangesList.entities,
  loading: activePairs.loading,
  totalItems: activePairs.totalItems,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEntities,
  getExchangesList,
};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ActivePairs);
```

How I can reload the table data when I change the select menu item? I would like to reload the data from the table data with the new selected `exchageId` param.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(fn, deps);
```

As we can see in the React documentation, the way we use the effect hook looks like this:
,fn is the effectful function, and deps is an array of values it depends on. Every time the component renders, React checks if all the values in the deps array are still the same. If any of them has changed since the last render, fn is run again.,All right, so far all the examples exhibit the same behavior. The effect simply doesn't run again if the dependency value doesn't change.

So you only need to give the useEffect hook  `exchageId` as deps and `the component's loading function` as fn,  then UseEffect will rerenders your component.

Comment: How I need to modify m code in order to use it?